# Mockito giving InvalidUseOfMatchersException incorrectly?

Tags: java, mockito

I don't understand what is going on in my class. I have a method that takes a List and a string. I am trying to mock it out using mockito so that it will return null. This is the code that I have:

`when(myClass.myMethod(anyList(), anyString())).thenReturn(null);`

I'm getting a standard `InvalidUseOfMatchersException`

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
1 matchers expected, 2 recorded:

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
...
```

But I really don't understand it. I am using matchers correctly - aren't `anyList()` and `anyString()` both matchers?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out, I was trying to do a when on a real method, and not a mocked method. The error message did not really help me figure that out...